# Scrapy crawl with next page doesn't work

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to crawl one website ,but it doesn't work when I crawl the next page, here is the spider code? where is wrong ,please tell me ,thanks very much.

```
import scrapy
from crawlAll.items import CrawlallItem

class ToutiaoEssayJokeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "duanzi"
    allowed_domains = ["http://duanziwang.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://duanziwang.com/category/duanzi/page/1']

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath("//article[@class='excerpt excerpt-nothumbnail']"):
            item = CrawlallItem()
            item['Title'] = sel.xpath("//header/h2/a/text()").extract_first()
            item['Text'] = sel.xpath("//p[@class='note']/text()").extract_first()
            item['Views'] = sel.xpath("//p[1]/span[@class='muted'][2]/text()").extract_first()
            item['Time'] = sel.xpath("//p[1]/span[@class='muted'][1]/text()").extract_first()
            yield item
        next_page = response.xpath("//ul/li[@class='next-page']/a/@href").extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

I have used print(next_page) to test if the next_page value if true or not,and it's true ,it give me a link address like this:http://duanziwang.com/category/duanzi/page/2' ,So what's wrong with my code ?

Comment: Can you share console logs from your crawl? (with the stats at the end)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `allowed_domains` parameter is faulty. It should not contain http in this case, usually it's best just to keep domain with top level domain i.e. domain.com

If your run your spider and observe the logs you'll see this:

```
[scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'duanziwang.com': <GET http://duanziwang.com/category/duanzi/page/2>
```

So try:

```
    allowed_domains = ["duanziwang.com"]
```